# Renaming a existing closed file but "Name" method showing error

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to save a file but before that I am checking if the same name file already exists in the same folder, if it's there, I rename the old existing file (add a timestamp to it's name) and move it to a different folder location. For renaming I am using "Name" method but it's showing error.

I have already tested that a file with same name already exists.The timestamp to be added is also coming up. Below is the code.

```
Dim Test As String

  On Error Resume Next
    Test = Dir(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B5").Text)
  On Error GoTo 0

  If Test = "" Then
    fileexist = False

  Else
    fileexist = True
    Timestamp = CStr(FileDateTime(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B5").Text))

    Newname = Left((ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B5").Text), Len((ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B5").Text)) - 5) & Timestamp & ".xlsx"

    Name (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B5").Text) As Newname
'*** Just this last above statment is giving error
End if
```

The file already exists so why is the Name method giving error? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What you doing there is kinda declare **Name** as a variable (although you haven't used `Dim`). To rename a file, have a look at `FileSystemObject`. Even then, you cannot rename a file that has the running macro because the file is open

Comment: Thanks for help, but I am trying to rename a file that is actually closed, I am trying to rename it because it has the same name with which I intend to save a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe give this a try :

```
Sub tryme()


Dim test As String

  On Error Resume Next
    test = Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B5").Text)
  On Error GoTo 0

  If test = "" Then
    fileexist = False

  Else
    fileexist = True
    Timestamp = CStr(FileDateTime(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B5").Text))

    newname = Left((ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B5").Text), Len((ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B5").Text)) - 5) & Format(Timestamp, "ddmmmyyyy") & ".xlsm"

     ThisWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & newname

End If



End Sub
```

If **the path is in B5** then just do as follow :

```
Dim Test As String

  On Error Resume Next
    Test = Dir(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B5").Text)
  On Error GoTo 0

  If Test = "" Then
    fileexist = False

  Else
    fileexist = True
    Timestamp = CStr(FileDateTime(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B5").Text))

    Newname = Left((ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B5").Text), Len((ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B5").Text)) - 5) & Format(Timestamp, "ddmmmyyyy") & ".xlsx"

    'Name (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B5").Text) As Newname
     ThisWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Newname 

End if
```

Comment: Thanks but I can't use SaveAs because I am not renaming an open file, actually I am trying to rename an existing closed file just because it's name matches the name with which I want to save another file.

Comment: @Repairer then do this : `Name ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B5").Text As  ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & 
 Newname` with my code.

Comment: @Repairer If your issue is solved May I ask you to accept [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57309771/11167163)

Comment: Thanks Dorian, the issue has been solved on similar line...Great help

Comment: @Repairer Where was the issue ?

Comment: I was trying to add the time (FileDateTime) to the file being saved and it was putting ":" and blanks in the name which was constantly giving error..hadn't thought of that earlier..thanks for the help

Comment: @Repairer Please Accept this answer so, Glad I could help you. [Go there to see how to accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). By accepting this answer it will set your issue as Solved and help the comunity